# Visualforce : apex:param value=""

Tags: apex, visualforce

In almost all the [examples](https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/the-usage-of-apexparam-in-visualforce-page/) where `apex:param` is used in conjunction with `apex:actionfunction` I have seen the `value` attribute of `apex:param` is `""`.

Can someone explain the logic behind this ?

I went through the doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) but still I am not clear about the usage of apex:param tag.

My  understanding is `apex:param` sets the controller variable mentioned in `assignTo` with the value mentioned in the `value` attribute.

If my understanding is right then why `value` attribute is always set to `""` in `apex:param` tag.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Hmm...I am also interested in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apex:actionFunction` will almost always have parameters assign the attribute `value=""`, because the parameter will be provided by the JavaScript call. However, `value` is a required attribute for `apex:param`, so you need to provide *something*, but the value itself is meaningless because the calling script will provide the appropriate value.

Comment: Yikes I just edited my post

Comment: @AaronWilfred It's okay, I was still here anyways. Glad I could help!